# Is there any way to use Angular / flex-layout API in Typescript file in Angular 11 project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Angular Flex Layout is very useful while working with Angular Material, Is there any way to consume the flex layout API in the TypeScript file?

For example from [this URL](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxShow-API), is there any way to get the MediaQueries values in the TypeScript file?

```js
breakpoint  mediaQuery
xs  'screen and (max-width: 599px)'
sm  'screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959px)'
md  'screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1279px)'
lg  'screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1919px)'
xl  'screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 5000px)'
lt-sm   'screen and (max-width: 599px)'
lt-md   'screen and (max-width: 959px)'
lt-lg   'screen and (max-width: 1279px)'
lt-xl   'screen and (max-width: 1919px)'
gt-xs   'screen and (min-width: 600px)'
gt-sm   'screen and (min-width: 960px)'
gt-md   'screen and (min-width: 1280px)'
gt-lg   'screen and (min-width: 1920px)'
```

I mean in the Angular TypeScript file, I can consume the media query for `SMALL`, `LARGE` and `MEDIUM` screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to use these media queries inside TypeScript files within Angular, but it's a bit hidden.

You can use the [Breakpoint Observer API from Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) which provides you with the same media queries as used in Angular's FlexLayout API, [specified in Material Design](https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#breakpoints).

Predefined list of breakpoints (the widths used may not be completely obvious, but together with the media queries in Material Design it can be traced back):

```js
export declare const Breakpoints: {
    XSmall: string;
    Small: string;
    Medium: string;
    Large: string;
    XLarge: string;
    Handset: string;
    Tablet: string;
    Web: string;
    HandsetPortrait: string;
    TabletPortrait: string;
    WebPortrait: string;
    HandsetLandscape: string;
    TabletLandscape: string;
    WebLandscape: string;
};
```

This list can be expanded to your needs. [A simple example can be found here as a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6yxelm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Steps to follow:

1. Import `LayoutModule` into your `app.module.ts` and add it to imports.

```js
import { LayoutModule } from "@angular/cdk/layout";
```

2. Import `BreakpointObserver`, `Breakpoints` and `BreakpointState` inside your component.

```js
import {
  BreakpointObserver,
  Breakpoints,
  BreakpointState
} from "@angular/cdk/layout";
```

3. Add `BreakpointObserver` to the constructor.
4. Inside your `ngOnInit`, add the observing query for a specific viewport (list), as specified inside the Breakpoints list. The list is an array and can hold multiple values:

```js
[Breakpoints.Small, Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait]
```

Code combined:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  viewportWidth: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpointObserver
      .observe([Breakpoints.Small, Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait])
      .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
        if (state.matches) {
          this.viewportWidth = "  I am INSIDE the breakpoint";
        } else {
          this.viewportWidth = "  I am OUTSIDE the breakpoint";
        }
      });
  }
}
```

[Final code on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6yxelm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Feel free to play around to your needs.